# Is there a 4-dimensional picture making a geometrical proof of Heron's formula

Tags: geometry, volume, polyhedra

Heron's formula states that if you have a triangle $T \subset \Bbb R^2$of sides $a,b,c$ then the hypervolume of a right-angled hyper-parallelepiped (is there a better word for this) of sides $a+b+c,a+b-c,a+c-b,b+c-a$ is $4$ times the hypervolume of $T \times T$.

Is there a procedure to cut them up into a finite number of (polyedral, Banach–Tarski is not quite welcome here) pieces and rearrange them and/or add a finite number of identical pieces to both shapes, to show that they have equal hypervolume ?

For comparison I'm thinking of a geometrical proof of Pythagoras' indentity with a square inscribed in a another square.

I would want a procedure that's mostly independant on $a,b,c$ (requiring the triangle to be acute would be okay I guess), for example with endpoints whose coordinates are affine functions on $a,b,c$ and the coordinates of the triangles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this. [n-category cafe](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2011/02/herons_formula.html)

[Heron's formula for 4-dimensional perspective](http://www.southalabama.edu/mathstat/personal_pages/carter/Heron_for_pub.pdf)